# In C, I'm struggling with Pointers

Tags: c

I have this code that I'm using for something else, but, boiled it down to the root problem I think. If I enter 5 for the scanf variable when I run it, the printf out is 0,16. I don't understand why this is giving me 16 for *pScores?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int a=0;
  int sum=0;
  scanf("%d",&a);
  int scores[a];
  int *pScores = &scores[0];
  printf("%d, %d\n",scores[0],*pScores);
}
```

Comment: Well, you haven't stored any data in `scores[0]` yet.  I would expect your code to print the same uninitialized value twice, but it's a weird and not-too-useful situation.  What happens if you actually fill in some data?

Comment: There's no need to use `sizeof` to calculate `size`. It will be the same as `a`.

Comment: Are you intending for this to be an exercise in "Variable-Length Arrays"?

Comment: Yea I meant to delete the size line of code, it's for something else. I'm just trying to understand why I keep getting 16 for *pScores

Comment: @SteveSummit Even if nothing is entered, shouldn't `scores[0]` and `*pScores` produce the same garbage?

Comment: @Barmar: No! The Schroedinger wavefunction does not collapse!

Comment: @Barmar I would certainly think so, yes.

Comment: I'm only able to reproduce this when I enable optimization. The optimizer detects the uninitialized array and compiles the array indexing differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are declaring an array

```
int scores[a];
```

and then printing out the value of `scores[0]` in two different ways.  However, you have not stored anything into any of the elements of the `scores` array, so the values there are *indeterminate*.

Whether use of uninitialized (and therefore indeterminate) values in this way actually rises to the level of *Undefined Behavior* is a surprisingly deep and actually somewhat contentious question.  (See the comment thread raging at the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74736264/in-c-im-struggling-with-pointers/74736304#74736304).)  Nevertheless, printing an uninitialized value like this isn't terribly useful.  If you fill in a well-defined value to at least `scores[0]`, I believe you'll find that both `scores[0]` and `*pScores` will print the same — that same — value.

Now, you might expect that the uninitialized value — whatever it is — would at least be consistent no matter how you print it (and I might agree with you), but when it comes to gray areas like this, and especially when a modern compiler starts leveraging every nuance of the rules in performing aggressive optimizations, the end results can be pretty surprising.  When I tried your program, I got the same number printed twice (that is, I couldn't initially reproduce your result), but as suggested by Barmar in a comment, when I turned on optimization (with `-O3`), I started seeing conflicting results, also.

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behavior, caused by reading a variable with automatic storage duration whose value is indeterminate.

In **6.2.4 Storage durations of objects** one finds the following rule

> For such an object that does have a variable length array type, its lifetime extends from the declaration of the object until execution of the program leaves the scope of the declaration. If the scope is entered recursively, a new instance of the object is created
> each time. **The initial value of the object is indeterminate.**

Then in **J.2 Undefined behavior**:

> The behavior is undefined in the following circumstances
>
> ...
>
> - The value of an object with automatic storage duration is used while it is indeterminate.
>
> ...

Among permitted very weird outcomes when dealing with indeterminate values is that they have a different value each time you read them.  The Schroedinger wavefunction does not collapse!

Comment: While this is certainly allowed by the language spec, it's still surprising. Why would it generate different code for the two expressions? But maybe the compiler notices that it's not initialized, so doesn't actually generate any code to read it, and random stack garbage is being passed to printf.

Comment: Looking at the generated code would be instuctive. OTOH, explaining why UB produces any specific result is just out of curiosity.

Comment: Indeterminate, yes, but it's not clear the posted code is actually undefined.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457) and in particular its [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11962457/why-is-using-an-uninitialized-variable-undefined-behavior/11965368#11965368).

Comment: @SteveSummit: It's absolutely UB, standard citations added to answer.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Steve Summit is correct, the behavior is not defined. J.2 is  non-normative; it is not an authoritative part of the standard, and it is in error on this point. The behavior is not undefined; it is defined to behave as if `scores[0]` has an indeterminate value. This is because, as you note, C 2018 6.2.4 6 says the value becomes indeterminate when the declaration is reached, and 3.19.2 says an indeterminate value is an unspecified value or a trap representation…

Comment: @BenVoigt I see you've commented at the answer I linked to.  We may be seeing some aspect of the "big mess" that  Jens Gustedt was referring to, with a "gap between what is intended behavior and what is actually written up".

Comment: @EricPostpischil: An unspecified value is *also* allowed to behave weirdly.

Comment: … There could be undefined behavior if a trap representation arose, but most modern C implementations do not have trap representations for the `int` type, so an indeterminate value cannot be a trap representation in such a C implementation. Aside from that, nothing else in the authoritative part of the C standard says the behavior would be undefined. 6.3.2.1 2 does say uses of uninitialized automatic objects have undefined behavior, but that does not apply because `scores` is an array and so could not have been declared `register` as needed for 6.3.2.1 2.

Comment: @BenVoigt Don't know where my head was on that one...

Comment: @BenVoigt: “Behave weirdly” is not undefined behavior. An indeterminate value may behave as if it has a different value each time it is used, but it **must** as if it does have some value, possibly including a trap representation in C implementations that have them. In other words, if the C implementation does not have a trap representation for `int`, then `printf("%d\n", scores[0]);` **must** print some representable `int` value; it cannot do anything else, e.g., terminate the program, as would be allowed if the behavior were undefined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: J.2 is good enough for me.  It expressly says this case is undefined behavior.

Comment: The table of contents says “Annex J (informative) Portability issues”. It is not a normative part of the standard. All of the normative annexes are marked “normative”, and they only define optional features. The C standard that specifies what implementations are to do in order to conform to the standard is chapters 1 to 7.

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Appendix J is still a good way to understand the intent of the authors.  If there's a conflict between that and the normative text, there's a very strong chance that the defect will be resolved by changing the normative text.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Your opinion about how the standard will be changed is very nice but entirely irrelevant. The normative part of the standard says that `scope[0]` has an indeterminate value, not that using it has undefined behavior.